# Dependencies of xparse package

Tags: packages, texlive, xparse, dependencies

Recently I have used a `xparse` package, and, surely some preprint servers doesn't have this package in their system, like, for example, https://arxiv.org. While you try to submit [to arXiv] the document

[image]

which involves `xparse` package you will get something like

[image]

Which I think refers us to some package on which `xparse` is dependent on, but

**Question** What are these packages `xparse` dependent on ?

PS Finally, including all packages to the arXiv submission, the following problem has come

[image]

Comment: `\RequirePackage{expl3}[2018-04-12]`  You should get an error message for an older version.

Comment: you would need xparse from 2016 to be compatible with that texlive 2016 installation, archives of old texlive are available.. but xparse was in texlve 2016 are you sure it is not available, why do you need to upload a 2019 version?

Comment: @David Carlisle yes, it is correct answer and I came across with the same conclusion. In case if one wants to use xparse within arxiv submission, it should be avoided a use of so-called "e-variables" which were introduced in the next version of xparse, so even in case of attachment of all requred packages to submission, one would still has a compile error. The only solution is to avoid use of new xparse, or rewrite existing xparse expression in terms of older xparse syntax, which is supported by arxiv tex live 2016