# xparse package safe for journal submissions?

Tags: xparse, incompatibility, journal-publishing, journal

**Tldr:** I'm using xparse to define commands with optional parameters. I would like to use these new commands in submissions to journals (think of Elsevier or Springer etc journals). Before doing so I would like to know if this will cause problems when compiling the paper on the journal server or for publication.

I have a similar question to:
[Dependencies of xparse package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512251/dependencies-of-xparse-package)

I (recently) came across xparse and I really like it! By now I have redefined my commonly used commands with optional parameters (alternatively think of overloaded functions). As a concrete example consider the probability .
In this case I have:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}

%This allows to use optional arguments in latex \def type definitions
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{mmm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}
   {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% probability
\NewDocumentCommand\Prob{gg}{%
\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{
\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#2}{\mathbb{P}}{\mathbb{P}_{#2}}
}{
\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#2}{\mathbb{P}\left(#1\right)}{\mathbb{P}_{#2}\left(#1\right)}
}
}
```

Using this definition I can now write `\Prob` to get just the , but `\Prob{A}` gives (A), while `\Prob{}{X}` gives <sub>X</sub> and finally `\Prob{A}{X}` gives <sub>X</sub>(A).

This is very convenient for me, and also, if I decide to change for Pr instead of I can just change the definition at one place.
I would like to use this type of xparse syntax for journal submissions, think of math/stats oriented journals of Elsevier, Springer etc, but I am afraid that this will not work on the journal side.
In a first step, one typically only needs to provide a pdf which of course would be fine, but if the paper is accepted, the journal compiles the LaTeX code on their installation (with their layout classes etc). If xparse causes a problem at this point I would have to manually go through the document and search / replace the occurrences in the correct way.

I would like to spare me (and my possible co-authors) this horrible fate.
My questions is therefore if anyone has experiences with xparse for journal submissions or any other comments that help me to asses weather or not I should use (or suggest using) xparse when writing a paper.

---

Here is a minimal working example just to make sure it's clear what I intend to use xparse for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{xparse}

%This allows to use optional arguments in latex \def type definitions
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF}{mmm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}
   {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% probability
\NewDocumentCommand\Prob{gg}{%
\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{
\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#2}{\mathbb{P}}{\mathbb{P}_{#2}}
}{
\IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#2}{\mathbb{P}\left(#1\right)}{\mathbb{P}_{#2}\left(#1\right)}
}
}

\begin{document}

Some examples for $\Prob$:
\begin{align}
&\Prob\\
&\Prob{A}\\
&\Prob{}{X}\\
&\Prob{A}{X}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: xparse has been part of the standard distributions for ages so is probably OK to use (except for journals that explicitly list that no other packages should be used, you need to check in each case) but I would avoid using `g` .  In current latex you do not need the `xparse` package to use `\NewDocumentCommand` it is already defined in the format but the `g` option is deprecated and not defined by default, to use `g` you have to explicitly load the legacy `xparse` package to define these additional forms.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the feedback, that helps me a lot. I'm also avoiding the ``g`` option from now on - thank you for the hint!

Comment: Are there any specific journals you’re wondering about? That would help make the answer less open-ended.

Comment: @Davislor I kept the journal in question vague since I would like to use my new commands when I start writing a (possible) paper without having to think about the final outlet from the start (say if journal A supports xparse and B doesn't). Journals I would be interested in are (in no particular order) for example: JMVA, Bernoulli, JASA, JRSSB, Stat. & Prob. letters, ...